# Hide the drop down menu when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu with checkboxes inside. I want to close the dropdown when the users click outside.

My code is:

```
<form>
<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
        <select>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes" id="checkboxes">
        @{ 
            if (ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee == null || ((IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.ActiveUsersList>)ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee).Count() == 0)
            {
                //@:<h3>No records were processed.</h3>

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var usr in ViewBag.DataActiveEmployee)
                {                   
                        <label id="userName">@usr.EmployeeName</label>     
                        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" name="search_emp" id="search_emp" value=@usr.EmployeeName>
                @:
        }
            }
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var expanded = false;
checkboxes.style.display = "none";
function showCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    if (!expanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = "block";
        expanded = true;
    } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = "none";
        expanded = false;
    }
}

$('multiselect').click(function () {
    $("#checkboxes").hide();
});
```

The problem is inside the second function of JavaScript because when I press outside, nothing is happening.

Please help.

Comment: What happens if you put the onclick attribute on the form itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `event.target` to handle click events:

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).on('click', '.multiselect .selectBox', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $('#checkboxes').show();
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {  
  if (e.target.id != 'checkboxes' && $(e.target).closest('#checkboxes').length == 0) {
    $('#checkboxes').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#checkboxes,
.multiselect {
  padding:15px;
  border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

.selectBox { display: inline; }

#checkboxes { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox">
        <select>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes" id="checkboxes">
        <label id="userName">Employee 1</label>     
        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" name="search_emp" id="emp_1" value="val_1">
        <label id="userName">Employee 1</label>     
        <input class="checked" type="checkbox" name="search_emp" id="emp_1" value="val_1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tryied what you suggest and its not working. Actually I have this error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**  I don't understand why

Comment: Is jQuery loaded when you call this function? This message tells you that the code does not recognize the $ symbol (jQuery alias)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the target click on dom is the dropdown itself or not as

```
$(document).on("click", function(event){
        var $trigger = $(".checkboxes");
        if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
            $(".checkboxes").hide();
        }            
    });
```

It should work.