# How to close my dropdown when other areas clicked by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple dropdown for my framework ..., I want to close it when other areas except dropdown clicked like Bootstrap.

This is my code :

```
$('.ji-dropdown-click button').click(function () {
    var animationObject = $(this).parent().find('.ji-dropdown-menu').data('animation');
    $(this).parent().find('.ji-dropdown-menu').toggle().addClass('animated' + ' ' + animationObject);
});
```

Can you please help me ? Thanks ...

Comment: try this you have to identify if the user click from the outside of your element
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561315/hide-the-drop-down-menu-when-clicking-outside/38561407#38561407 refer to this

Comment: Thanks both, But @AnuradhS It was exactly that I wanted ... Thanks Again ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$('body *:not(.ji-dropdown-click)').click(function() {
   $('ji-dropdown-click').hide(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But It doesn't work ..., I put that in my inside my code & outside my code but It always hide it ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).click( function(){
    $('.ji-dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

It should work.

Comment: On a side note, jquery's animate functions have poor performance. I would suggest using [Velocity.js](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity)